# Is it possible to use a multipart upload with aws-java-sdk-s3 without using ETags?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I want to upload files using multipart uploads but it isn't suitable for me to use ETags (because parts can be uploaded through different servers). Is it possible to create a concatenated file with files which already have been uploaded and use the names of this files or something else but not ETags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't possible.

It is OK for different servers to upload their parts, but you need to figure out a way for them to notify a central authority of ETags that they received from S3, so that the central authority can *complete* the request at the end.

Comment: This is correct.  Coordinating the part-etags is also a critical part of ensuring that the uploaded object's integrity is intact.

Comment: You are right. The best way I found is the getting summaries of parts after last part was uploaded and finish the upload. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadListParts.html